# Recursively changing externs path in Repo

Tags: svn

Hi can someone tell me if this is possible?

Because of some complications of wandisco we have had to move some of repo's into sub folders instead of directly off the root URL, so while before we had:
url://svn.server/Products
and
url://svn.server/Firmwares

it is now

url://svn.server/Projects/Products
url://svn.server/Projects/Firmwares

Now in the Products repo we have external reference to the Firmwares which take the form of:
^/../Firmwares/path/to/firmware

With this new change we need to change these external references to:

^/../../Projects/Firmwares/path/to/firmware

This is easy enough to do but we have been developing for a long time now and have a fair size team so there are a large  number of Product Tags, Team scratchpads and general development branches that all all now broken and spending the effort changing each one by hand would be quite tedious.

My question is, Is there a way to recursively change the external properties of all branches in our repo in one go? Obviously I understand that this can be a  dangerous exercise so we would obviously backup the SVN repo before doing so.

We also need to be able to do this server side, as checking out the entire repo on the client would also take a long time (each project is quite a few gigabytes)